# Creating COM object via ssh (issue with AutoCAD.Application)

Tags: python, ssh, com, autocad

I'm trying to run the following simple pyhton script from ssh:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import comtypes.client

acad = comtypes.client.CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")
acad.Visible = True
```

This works fine from the local machine but not via ssh, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "C:/Ab*******/comtypetest.py", line 6, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    acad = comtypes.client.CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 227, in CreateObject                                                                                                                                                                                 
    clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid                                                                                                                                                                                              
    _CLSIDFromProgID(unicode(progid), byref(inst))                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 945, in GetResult                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
WindowsError: [Error -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

Not that creating InternetExplorer.Application works from ssh but windows doest not get Visible.

Can someone please tell me how to avoid this issue?

**EDIT:**
The script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import win32com.client
lib = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")
```

Also give an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "C:/Ab*******/comtypetest.py", line 6, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    acad = comtypes.client.CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 227, in CreateObject                                                                                                                                                                                 
    clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid                                                                                                                                                                                              
    _CLSIDFromProgID(unicode(progid), byref(inst))                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 945, in GetResult                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
WindowsError: [Error -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

As for the first one, IE is launching without showing up.

Comment: How did you manage to fix it? If possible reply to bbg@ardorallc.com. Thank you.

Comment: It has been a long time, here is a quick answer: finally a resigned myself to create a background script driven by w webserver.

But I think I found a trick to do it via ssh, will put here answer if I remember it.

Comment: You can also look this attempt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242343/createprocessasuser-done-how-to-control-the-created-process