# CreateProcessAsUser done! How to control the created process?

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to launch an app as another user, this works perfectly, the process is created, but I don't know how to handle the created process as I usually do with comtypes or win32com (COM interface), here is the script:

```
import win32process
import win32security
import win32con
import cgi 
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

domain = '.'
username = 'me'
password = 'mypwd'

try:
    token = win32security.LogonUser (
        username,
        domain,
        password,
        win32security.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
        win32security.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
    )
except win32security.error:
    print "Failed"
else:
    appname = "C:/path/to/app.exe"
    startup = win32process.STARTUPINFO()
    priority = win32con.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
    handle, thread_id ,pid, tid = win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(token, appname, None, None, None, True, priority, None, None, startup)
```

Usually, when I don't need to run the process as another user, I use (for example with win32com):

```
import win32com.client
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("app.Application")
```

Then I can control the application with the `app` object

Being the same library, I guess I can do something with `handle` or `thread_id` together with `win32com.client` keeping the same user, but I don't found anything, can you please help me.

Comment: How do you want to control the process? I've written debugger loops that allow me to step by statement. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to use the COM interface offered by the app, excel for example

Comment: `CreateProcessAsUser` sounds like its the wrong tool for the job. You should look for Python bindings for the COM object.

Comment: I didn't find any that permits to run the app as another user, do you know such a tool?